# what is the current popular TCP congestion control algorithm in Linux

Tags: linux, tcp, congestion-control

TCP Reno, HSTCP, STCP or Fast TCP? Or we can change the algorithm with current popular kernel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any recent kernel (3.14.0 is the source version I'm looking at), offers a handful of congestion control algorithms:

1. Binary Increase Congestion (BIC) control
2. Version 2.0 of BIC-TCP
3. TCP Westwood+ (a modification of Reno)
4. H-TCP (another modification of Reno)
5. Sally Floyd's High Speed TCP (RFC 3649) congestion control
6. TCP-Hybla
7. TCP Vegas
8. Scalable TCP
9. TCP Low Priority (TCP-LP)
10. TCP Veno
11. YeAH-TCP (I reckon this is a Reno modification)
12. TCP-Illinois (a modification of Reno)

What you actually are using or have available depend on options chosen when the kernel has been compiled. You can see what's available with `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_available_congestion_control` and control what is actually used by fiddling with the file `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_congestion_control`.

In case you have enabled kernel config inclusion in to the running kernel, you can also see what is compiled in with `zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONG`. The kernel configuration, e.g. `make menuconfig`, has more detailed descriptions of each algorithm, but of course nothing beats reading the source, available in your kernel source tree under `net/ipv4/` (see files `tcp_*.c`, filenames are self-explanatory).

Comment: thanks Sami for your detailed explaination